# Automate the Populating of Subplots with different data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#data
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(x**2)
y3 = np.cos(x**2)
#plot       
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax1.set_title('lalalala')
ax2.plot(x, y2)
ax3.plot(x, y3)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
```

Instead of entering ax1 to ax3 and y1 to y3 manually, I was wondering if there was any way to loop over the ax's and y's to populate the plot. I am aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828771/automate-the-populating-of-subplots) but the best answer that is given there does not loop over the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just put in a list all you want and add subplots in a loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#data
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)

y = [np.sin(x), np.sin(x**2), np.cos(x**2)]
title = ['y1','y2','y3']

#plot       
numPlots = len(y)
f = plt.figure()
ax = []
for i in range(numPlots):
    ax.append(f.add_subplot(numPlots,1,i+1))
    ax[i].plot(x, y[i])
    ax[i].set_title(title[i])
    f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: Subplots created in a loop]